# How to bind data of angularjs inside onClick as argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to bind Angularjs data inside `onClick` function,
I have tried, but it's not working.

In below example I want to bind index value inside `onclick` function. What's wrong with my code. Can anyone point out this..

```
/**Example:**/
<input type="text" ng-repeat="items in itemList" onClick=tab("{{$index}}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've done ...

```
ng-click="tab($index)"
```

This takes advantage of the fact that angular has it's own click; this allows for simpler variable declaration and passing.

Comment: actually i want to bind inside onClick="tab('$index')", not using ng-click().because it's asking for tab change.so i need unique data for call tab bro..

Comment: I'm going to have to say that I don't understand the need to to onClick versus ng-click.  The tab change will occur either way; in fact, I've successfully done this for a tabbed format within the last 60 days with ng-click.  The two click events function essentially the same; just a matter of which framework tracks and fires the event.  I'll keep a watch on this question; now I'm curious ... maybe if it's explained in more detail why you need the variance you'll get your answer.

Comment: Also, I don't think your question properly indicates why you need one over the other; you might want to adjust it.

Comment: Don't just use my code because I said so; if you have a valid reason, it might be something I need to learn ...

Comment: <input type="text" ng-repeat="items in itemList" ng-click=tab($index).